# NFS share turned read-only

Tags: centos, rhel, nfs

On an old RHEL 5 server, one of the NFS mounts turned readonly: running `touch foo` returns an error

```
touch: cannot touch `foo': Read-only file system
```

Moreover, in the output of `ls -l` UIDs and GIDs now are numeric: they are `1000712 1000002` and `1000719 1000002` instead of `nobody nobody`.

This is the relevant excerpt of `/etc/fstab`:

```
mynfsserver.example.org:/mypath       /mymount       nfs       vers=3,hard,intr,actimeo=1       0 0
```

This is the relevant excerpt of the output of `mount`:

```
mynfsserver.example.org:/mypath on /mymount type nfs (rw,nfsvers=3,hard,intr,actimeo=1,addr=10.2.3.4)
```

The command

```
showmount -e 10.2.3.4
```

produces an export list showing just a list of paths and, for each path, the IP addresses of the clients it is exported to.

---

The same share is mounted on a CentOS 7 server, and it works well there on read-write.
Relevant excerpt of `/etc/fstab`:

```
mynfsserver.example.org:/mypath       /mymount       nfs       vers=4,hard,intr,rw,actimeo=1       0 0
```

and relevant excerpt of the output of `mount`:

```
mynfsserver.example.org:/mypath on /mymount type nfs4 (rw,relatime,vers=4.0,rsize=1048576,wsize=1048576,namlen=255,acregmin=1,acregmax=1,acdirmin=1,acdirmax=1,hard,proto=tcp,timeo=600,retrans=2,sec=sys,clientaddr=10.2.5.6,local_lock=none,addr=10.2.3.4)
```

(As you may have noticed, the CentOS server uses NFS v4 while the RHEL server uses NFS v3. I've tried to specify NFS v4 for the RHEL server too, but this does not solve the issue.)

The command

```
showmount -e 10.2.3.4
```

returns an error `clnt_create: RPC: Port mapper failure - Timed out`

---

Kernel messages (`cat /var/log/messages`, `journalctl`, `dmesg`) do not show anything unusual on both servers.

What could be the problem?

Comment: Any relevant (sys)logs in both systems?

Comment: `UIDs and GIDs now are numeric` what are the numbers?

Comment: I have added this information in my question.

Comment: One thing that jumps out at me is that your RHEL5 server is using NFSv3 and your CentOS server is using NFSv4. Are they exported differently?

Comment: @roaima Cannot tell, I did not make the configuration, but this bugged me too.  I'll try to switch to NFSv4 on the RHEL 5 server and see what happens.

Comment: `showmount -e` (I think it's `-e`) will show you how the export is being offered to the client

Comment: @roaima Tried that, see edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved: simply, the RHEL client was set as read-only on the NFS server (which I don't manage, so I don't have any more information about it).